# ngx-charts-bar-vertical-normalized not displaying a percentage

Tags: html, angular, typescript, charts

I have a ngx-charts-bar-vertical-normalized, this function is ok. In this moment, when I put the click above the bar, they show me a percent. I need the number of percent always. Not only when I put the click above the bar.

I leave the code:

```html
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-normalized
    [view]="[1000, 400]"
    [results]="multi
    [xAxis]="showXAxis"
    [yAxis]="showYAxis"
    [legend]="showLegend"
    [legendTitle]="''"
    [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" 
    [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
    [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
    [tooltipTemplate]="tooltipTemplate"
    [customColors]="myColors"
    [showDataLabel]="true">

    <ng-template #tooltipTemplate let-model="model">
        <div style="padding: 5px; font-size: 15px;">
            <div>
                {{model.series}} <span style="font-size:20px;"> . </span>{{model.name}}
            </div> {{model.value}}%
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical-normalized>
```

The number that I said is `{{model.value}}`.
Can you help me?

Actually when I put the click above the bar, these show me the `model.value` (percent).

Comment: Welcome to the site, Tomás  Editing your question made me notice that you've left a `"` off the end of `[results]="multi`. Is that typo present in your real code?